# VS2013 compilation issues with regard to usage of _Bool

Tags: c, visual-studio, boolean, c99

I am compiling the following peice of code in VS2013,

```
#if (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L)
/* Inactive pre-processor block */
#else
/* Active pre-processor block */
#ifndef __bool_true_false_are_defined
typedef unsigned char _Bool;

#define bool  _Bool
#define false (0)
#define true  (1)
#define __bool_true_false_are_defined (1)

#endif /* __bool_true_false_are_defined */
#endif
```

where my objectives are as follows

- If the compiler supports C99 then donot  create a `_Bool` type, as it is already inbuilt.
- If the compiler does not suport C99, then create a custom `_Bool` type.

My observations are that the code enters the `#else` block (no C99 support), but still the compiler complains about `error C2632: 'char' followed by 'bool' is illegal`

The following are few questions I have w.r.to the above logic

1. Is the preprocesser check for C99 support correct ?
2. If answer to (1) is yes, then why isn't the C99 code block remains inactive in VS2013. I assumed VS2013 has C99 support.
3. If there is no C99 support in VS2013, then why does the compiler complain about the typedef of `_Bool`

Comment: [error C2632](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws579tt7.aspx)

Comment: I don't have VS2013 installed but 2012 was still on C89 (aka ansi C) support; I presume 2013 is the same.  Your code compiles for me.  Can you provide a full (but short) example program which demonstrates your error please?

Comment: @ BLUEPIXY, As per C2632, it indicates that `bool` has been made a proper type (not sure though, on the point that, from which version of VS the change was made). Does that mean C99 support is not there in VS2013, but there are some customizations w.r.to creating a proper type for _Bool

Comment: @simonc, I am adding the code in .c file. The above is the all of the test code snippet that I am trying to compile.

Comment: VS 2013 [implemented a number of C99 features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx) including _Bool. My guess is they may not have bumped __STDC_VERSION__ because the support is incomplete.

Comment: @Niger If that is the case, I beleive it is a bit of pain to manage the above such scenarios :(

Comment: You need to insert `#elif defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1800` before the `#else`

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if they already have defined it the other way arround, `_Bool` to expand to `bool`. Perhaps test additionally with

```
#if defined(_Bool) || defined(bool)
..
#endif
```